# beamer: not incrementing framenumber for "fully restricted" frames

Tags: latex, beamer

My documents often contain "fully restricted" frames of this form:

```
\begin{frame}<0>
    Lorem ipsum dolor.
\end{frame}
```

Because of the <0> at the end of the first line, frames like this do
not appear in the documents that I produce with pdflatex or xelatex.
But they still cause the framenumber counter to increment, which leads
to strange results.  Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[xelatex]{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \setbeamertemplate{footline}{\hfill\insertframenumber}
  \begin{frame}<0>{Frame A}
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}{Frame B}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

When I process this document with xelatex, I get a PDF document
containing one frame.  The framenumber in the footline of the frame is
2.  I would like it to be 1.  I could manually reset the frame counter
after every restricted frame, but in large documents with many such
frames, that is a hassle.  Is there any way to stop restricted frames
from incrementing the counter?

Comment: Comment for anyone brought here by search engine: you can find an entire community on the [TeX StackExchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/), where no TeX-related question is too small.  There are oodles of [beamer questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beamer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a new environment macro that contains the counter fix:

```
\newenvironment{restrictedframe}[1]
  {\begin{frame}<0>{#1}}
  {\end{frame} \addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}}
```

Comment: Thank you.  This works, provided that I change `\addtocounter{framecounter}` to `\addtocounter{framenumber}`.

Comment: With the current beamer version, the numbering will be off because now frames with `<0>` are automatically excluded from increasing the framecounter. Also there are many situations in which beamer needs to actually see `\end{frame}` and will freak out if you hide it away in a custom environment. If you really, really must do this, at least use the `environmnet` key to inform beamer about it:

Comment: `\newenvironment{restrictedframe}[2][]
  {\begin{frame}<0>[environment=restrictedframe,#1]\frametitle{#2}}
  {\end{frame}}`

Answer (score 4):

Beamer now automatically excludes frames which are hidden with `<0>` from increasing the frame counter. So the solution is now increadible easy:

do nothing :)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}<0>
  \frametitle{Frame A}
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Frame B}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Pre-v3.65 solution:

The frames can be excluded from the frame counter by using the `noframenumbering` option:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}<0>[noframenumbering]
  \frametitle{Frame A}
  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Frame B}
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```